# iMovie 10.1.1 crashes during color balancing

Tags: macos, crash, macos-mojave, imovie

I am a new Mac user editing a video using iMovie v.10.1.1 on Mojave 10.14.6. Each time I try to color balance the video, it crashes unexpectedly without providing an error message. This is true for all color balancing options: white balancing, color matching, etc. This happens on all videos. I have tried trashing my preferences since I read this is a source of trouble for iMovie, but this has no effect.

Is this a known bug? I can't find anything about it. Also, is there a more detailed error log I can read?

Comment: Try updating iMovie, see if it's been fixed since. Current version is 10.1.14 for Mojave. if no fix, we will need details of precisely which Mac you have.

Comment: That did it. Thank you!